# finding the next empty space in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an error where I am trying to load a player's name and score to the first open space of the array, but it is creating duplicates of that name over and over in the array. Thanks in advance

```
 Structure Player
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Score As Integer
End Structure

Public HighScores(100) As Player


 For i = 0 To 99
            If HighScores(i).Name = "" And HighScores(i).Score = 0 Then
                HighScores(i).Name = PlayerName
                HighScores(i).Score = CurrentScore
            Else
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by creating duplicates of the name. Kindly explain it bit more.

Comment: So it will put the player name and current score variables in multiple places of the array. Like Array(0) and Array(1) and Array(2) will all be the same name and score.

Comment: I would suggest using a Dictionary(Of String,Integer) or a List(Of Player) and checking if a player name already exists in the object before adding it.

Comment: I would add "Exit For" after setting the value in your IF Block. Thats why you are getting multiple entries of the same values.  Also, remove your else block. The for loop aready incriments i

Comment: Could you give an example of the Exit For code? Do you mean after the THEN ?

Comment: @David See my answer

Comment: Note that you don't need the `i += 1` in the `Else` block. `i` will be automatically incremented each time round the `For` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will set the supplied values in every empty index it finds. You need to stop setting the values (exit the loop) once you have found your empty index and set it's value.

```
For i = 0 To 99

   If HighScores(i).Name.Length = 0 AndAlso HighScores(i).Score = 0 Then 'Determines if the index is empty

       HighScores(i).Name = PlayerName
       HighScores(i).Score = CurrentScore   'Sets the values

       Exit For    'Exits the loop

    End If

Next
```

The above code will only run through the loop once if the first index matches your requirements, twice if the first index does not but the second does and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid looping through the array looking for an empty slot use a List(Of T) as suggested by  David Wilson in comments. The T stands for Type and Player is a Type. This restricts your list to only objects of type Player. I included a bit to sort your list using LINQ to Objects. There are in line comments. Although I think a list would be a better approach, The White Wolf's answer with the Exit For should solve your problem.

```
Structure Player
        Public Score As Integer
        Public Name As String
        'Added a constructor to the structure to make it easy to add new Player
        Public Sub New(myScore As Integer, myName As String)
            Score = myScore
            Name = myName
        End Sub
    End Structure
    Private lstScores As New List(Of Player)
    Private Sub BuildList()
        lstScores.Add(New Player(500, "Mathew"))
        lstScores.Add(New Player(200, "Mark"))
        lstScores.Add(New Player(300, "Luke"))
        lstScores.Add(New Player(700, "John"))
        'Sort and display list
        SortList()
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddScore(strName As String, intScore As Integer)
        lstScores.Add(New Player(intScore, strName))
    End Sub
    Private Sub SortList()
        'Note: the original lstScores is not changed
        Dim orderedList = From scorer In lstScores Order By scorer.Score Descending Select $"{scorer.Score} - {scorer.Name}"
        'orderedList is an IEnumerable(Of String) because the Select part of the LINQ query is a string.
        'Using .ToList provides the DataSource of the ListBox with the formatted strings
        'Display the sorted list in a list box
        ListBox1.DataSource = orderedList.ToList
    End Sub
```